# echo some letters

Tags: php

Hello im trying to echo only the 50 letters, but something in my code isnt ok, can someone take a look whats wrong?

```
<?php       
$id=18;         
$result=mysql_query("select * from article where id='$id'");        
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
$row = substr($row, 0,50);  
?>

<?php echo $row['info_en']; 
?>
```

Comment: You can't apply `substr()` on an array; it will just operate on the string `'Array'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is logical error in the code, Use the below code

```
<?php       
$id=18;         
$result=mysql_query("select * from article where id='$id'");        
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
$row['info_en']= substr($row['info_en'], 0,50);  
?>

<?php echo $row['info_en']; 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

What do you want to `substr` an Array? You could probably mean

```
$row['info_en'] = substr($row['info_en'], 0,50);
```

If you try to `substr` an Array you will get the string `"Array"`, then if you try to refer it as an Array you probably get nothing meaningful.